# SQL Query - Select one row or the other based on the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query producing the given result.

```
SELECT 
    p.BookingID, p.PaxID, p.LeadPax, p.FirstName AS LeadPaxName
FROM 
    [dbo].[BookingV2_Pax] p
WHERE
    p.[LeadPax] = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    PN.BookingID, PN.PaxID, PN.LeadPax, PN.LeadPaxName
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         p.BookingID, p.PaxID, p.LeadPax, p.FirstName AS LeadPaxName,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.BookingID ORDER BY p.PaxID) AS rn
     FROM 
         [dbo].[BookingV2_Pax] p
     WHERE 
         p.[LeadPax] = 0) PN
WHERE 
    PN.rn = 1
```

**Results:**

[image: booking pax results]

What I'm doing here is selecting the row which has `LeadPax = true` and selecting the first row from the other rows which has `LeadPax = false`

**What I want is selecting the either the row with `LeadPax = 1` OR `LeadPax = 0`.**

I understand that if this were a column related problem, I can use `CASE` or `COALESCE` but how do I do this with rows efficiently?

Also, any pointers on how to optimize the original query would be highly appreciated

Comment: Go to **CodeReview**, another **SE** site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

Generate the row number only when `LeadPax = False`. Then use `AND/OR` logic to get the relevant data

```
SELECT PN.BookingID,
       PN.PaxID,
       PN.LeadPax,
       PN.LeadPaxName
FROM   (SELECT p.BookingID,
               p.PaxID,
               p.LeadPax,
               p.FirstName AS LeadPaxName,
               case when PN.[LeadPax] = 0 then Row_number() OVER (partition BY p.BookingID ORDER BY p.PaxID) 
                else 1 end AS rn
        FROM   [dbo].[BookingV2_Pax] p) PN
WHERE  ( PN.rn = 1 AND PN.[LeadPax] = 0 )
        OR PN.[LeadPax] = 1
```

Comment: if LeadPax has only 0 and 1 values, you could write ELSE 1   in CASE     and use just  WHERE rn=1